# Custom HTTP server listening in a random IP

Tags: http, boost, server, multicast

I'm developing an HTTP server with Boost for an application which will only be used in LAN. The thing is that no one will be able to know the IP of the computer with the http server (no chance of doing it static), so I was thinking about making the HTTP server listen to a multicast address in order to know it before hand. The clients would connect to that multicast address and they wouldn't need to know the server ip.

My question: is there any other way of doing this more elegantly?

Thanks!

Comment: what about looking up the server IP with DNS?  If you don't have a static IP, then are you using DHCP?  And if so, something should be registering the computer name in DNS.  You shouldn't need to jump through multicast hoops just to find a server on your LAN with dynamic IP, people have been doing that for decades.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is have your TCP/HTTP server `bind` to port 0 and let the kernel allocate the port for you. Then call `getsockname` to find out the allocated port.

After that your server starts sending UDP datagrams to a predefined multicast address once every few seconds. Each datagram contains the name, address and port of your server.

The clients join the multicast group, receive the datagram and discover the server's name, address and port and connect.

---

Alternatively, instead of sending a datagram every few seconds, your server can listen on a predefined multicast group. The clients send a multicast datagram to the group to find where the server is. The server replies to that datagram with its name, address and port. This is similar to how [DNS service discovery with multicast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking#DNS-SD_with_multicast) works.

Comment: I though of that, but it's not what I need since users should be able to use chrome/mozilla/... to enter the website, so it won't be useful for me because they will need an extra app just to learn my IP and then connect to that address using the web browser.
What I'm looking for is them sending an HTTP request to a fixed IP and the server getting it regardless of its IP. So I would be able to switch between LANs easily. The way I want it, multicast wouldn't work for various reasons.

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to send an HTTP request to a multicast address and the server responding with a redirect to its IP?

Comment: @deuseux12 HTTP uses TCP but multicast works for connection-less protocols, such as IP and UDP.

Comment: Look into mDNS, it is standard and multiplatform.